# If f(x,y) is continuous with respect to x and bounded with respect to y, does there exist a subregion where f is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Suppose $f:D=[0,1]\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)$ can be unbounded in the whole D, for example: $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{y},y\neq 0$(and $0$ for $y=0$).What about a region in D?

Comment: **Hint:** The restriction of a continuous map on a bounded set is bounded.

Comment: Are you asking whether there exists a function $f:D\to\Bbb R$ such that for each fixed $y$ the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous,  for each fixed $x$ the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is bounded, but the function $f$ is unbounded on each non-empty open subset of $D$, right?

Answer (score 0):

There exists no function $f:D\to\Bbb R$ such that for each fixed $y$ the function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous,  for each fixed $x$ the function $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is bounded, but the function $f$ is unbounded on each subset of $D$ of the form $B\times [0,1]$, where $B\subset [0,1]$ is a non-empty open interval. Indeed, assume the converse and let $f$ be such a function. Then we can inductively define a sequence $x_n$ of points of $[0,1]$ and an non-empty open intervals $B_n\subset [0,1]$ such that for each $n$ we have $\overline{B_{n+1}}\subset B_n$, length of $B_n$ is at most $1/n$, and $f(x_n,t)>n$ for each $t\in B_n$. Since the metric space $[0,1]$ is complete, there exists a point $y\in\bigcap B_n=\bigcap\overline{B_n}$. Then $f(x_n,y)>n$ for each $n$, a contradiction.